# Como previnir SQL Injection (WHERE clause)?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Como posso me previnir de SQL Injection nesse caso?

```
<?php

//==== GET URL PARAMETER
$urlParam =  $_GET['u'];
    
$sql = "SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE keystring = '$urlParam'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: Utilize `mysqli_real_escape_string` ou utilize [Prepared Statment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Onde devo colocar "mysqli_real_escape_string" ?

Comment: Olá Victor, segue aqui como prevenir sqlinjection: [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/3635).